# Cannot create folder in any SharePoint Web application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When trying to create a new folder in a document library I get a bad request error '400'.  I am at a loss.  I have checked permissions, played with IIS settings, and tried just deleting and recreating the libraries.  This is happening on all sites so it is affecting the entire farm.

Comment: Can you create all other objects? Subsites, lists, libraries, etc? In the library's Advanced Settings section, are folders enabled?

Comment: Thats weird. Run SP Config Wizzard if it complete successfully. Make sure you have Site Collection Administrator and try it again.

Comment: Thanks for the help...I ended up just redoing the farm cause I had all sorts of random problems